# Why is my jQuery variable not working?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to turn my default colour choice into a variable as it is being used twice in two different functions. This is what I have tried (amongst other things) but it just doesn't seem to be working? Here is a JSFiddle of my code for anyone who could attempt to play with it? I just can't seem to get it to work, but it seems like it should be so easy? https://jsfiddle.net/q7bLwt8n/

```js
var defaultcolor = $(this).css("background-color", "#7fffd4");

$(document).ready(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
      $('#grid').append('<div class= square></div>');
    };
  };
  $(".square").mouseenter(function() {
    defaultcolor;
  });

  //clears the canvas and resets the color on hover back to #7fffd4//
  $("#clear").click(function() {
    $("#grid").effect("shake");
    $(".square").css("background-color", "white");
    $(".square").mouseenter(function() {
      defaultcolor;
    });
  });
  //creates a random color for each square when button is clicked//
  $("#randomcolor").click(function() {
    $(".square").mouseenter(function() {
      var randomColorChange = '#' + (Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF << 0).toString(16);
      $(this).css('background-color', randomColorChange);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: white;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #191919;
}

span {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #7fffd4;
}

.buttons {
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 480px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#clear,
#randomcolor,
#usersquares {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  background-color: #191919;
  color: white;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#grid {
  width: 484px;
  height: 484px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border: 2px solid #191919;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 30px 10px #b2b2b2;
}

.square {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<h1>Etch A <span>Sketch</span></h1>
<div class="buttons">
  <button id="clear">Clear Canvas</button>
  <button id="randomcolor">Random Colors</button>
  <button id="usersquares">Squares Per Side</button>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div id="grid"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: try this `class= "square"`

Comment: You're also missing a closing bracket for your square class in the css.

Comment: @DaniloBustos sorry for being stupid - where do i add that?

Comment: @HelderJulesDeBaere oops I didnt copy it into the box but it is in the actual document!

Comment: In the append  `$('#grid').append('<div class= "square"></div>');`

Comment: after background: white; and you don't need semi-colon closing the for loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `this` is evaluated when the interpreter parses the script. Because of this the value of `this` in `defaultcolor` is not the `this` you refer to in the mouse events.

Instead you could do something like this:

```
function set_default_color() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#7fffd4");
}

$(".square").mouseenter(set_default_color);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! so even adding '.square' instead of 'this' also would not work? in your suggestion - where would i add that function? outside of document ready also or inside of document ready?

Comment: @nickyheise I would add it where you currently have `var defaultcolor...`. Difference is that here we use a method which dynamically can alter its referenced variable, and in your code you attempt to reuse the value of a variable that has been evaluated earlier.

Comment: i just tried adding this but it didnt seem to work? i added
    function set_default_color() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#7fffd4");
    }
above document ready and then
    $(".square").mouseenter(set_default_color);
in the places where I had the functions set but when i reloaded the page no colour would show on the etch a sketch board!

Comment: @nickyheise I am not sure what the problem is then. I've created a simple jsfiddle that illustrates the use. If you have your code like that and it still does not work, you have another issue in your code somwhere. The jsfiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/4w5d6a3y/1/

Comment: `function set_default_color() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#7fffd4");
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  for(var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
    $('#grid').append('<div class= "square"></div>');
    }
  };
 $(".square").mouseenter(set_default_color);
  });`

is this how it should be implemented? thanks for your time!

Comment: i got it working! i had an extra }); floating around somewhere!! thanks so much!!!!!

Comment: No problem @nickyheise :)